# Как отключить сортировку пунктов меню по алфавиту на WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Установил тему, поставил меню

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location'  => 'top',
        'menu_id'         => 'top-menu',
        'menu_class'      => 'art-menu',
        'container'       => 'ul',
        'container_class' => 'art-menu',
        'link_before'     => '<span class="l"></span><span class="r"></span><span class="t">',
        'link_after'      => '</span>'
    ) );
```

Есть проблема, пункты меню сортируются по алфавиту вне зависимости от заданного в админке порядка пунктов меню

Comment: Как вариант, использовать функцию wp_get_nav_menu_items. `$items = wp_get_nav_menu_items('top-menu', array('orderby' => 'date'));`

Comment: Значит это код не от того меню